# decrypt a KMS encrypted document fetched from S3 presigned url

Tags: java, amazon-kms, pre-signed-url

I have a use case where I am getting an XML file from a S3 pre-signed url. The file is encrypted with a customer managed KMS key.

Code Snippet:-

```
final URL presignedUrl = new URL(s3Uri);
 try (InputStream inputStream = presignedUrl.openStream()) {
    byte[] encryptedData = inputStream.readAllBytes();
    ByteBuffer encryptedByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(encryptedData);
    AWSKMS kmsClient = AWSKMSClientBuilder.standard()
                       .withCredentials() // credentials
                       .withRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2)
                       .build();
    DecryptRequest decryptRequest = new DecryptRequest();
    decryptRequest.withCiphertextBlob(encryptedByteBuffer);
    decryptRequest.withKeyId(KMS_KEY_ARN);
    DecryptResult decryptResponse = kmsClient.decrypt(decryptRequest); // Error is being thrown here
  }
```

Error:-

```
{
        "class": "com.amazonaws.SdkClientException",
        "message": "Unable to execute HTTP request: Broken pipe (Write failed)",
        "stackTrace": "com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Broken pipe (Write failed)\n\tat com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1219)\n\tat com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1165)\n\tat com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:814)\n\tat com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:781)\n\tat com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:755)\n\tat com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:715)\n\tat com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:697)\n\tat com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:561)\n\tat com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:541)\n\tat com.amazonaws.services.kms.AWSKMSClient.doInvoke(AWSKMSClient.java:9322)\n\tat com.amazonaws.services.kms.AWSKMSClient.invoke(AWSKMSClient.java:9289)\n\tat com.amazonaws.services.kms.AWSKMSClient.invoke(AWSKMSClient.java:9278)\n\tat com.amazonaws.services.kms.AWSKMSClient.executeDecrypt(AWSKMSClient.java:2197)\n\tat com.amazonaws.services.kms.AWSKMSClient.decrypt(AWSKMSClient.java:2166)\n\tat 
}
```

Any leads what could be the reason? How can I fix this?
Thanks